# SAS: duplicate rows and change some variables

Tags: sas, rows

I have these data, looking something like this:

```
data test;                     
   input ID $ Week Age Weight City $ Sex $;  
   datalines;           
John 2  64 145 OK M
Gary 3  46 176 OM M

;                          


run;
```

So, here I have to rows, and I wish to do the following:
-duplicate each row as many times needed to get every combination of changing the three variables *Week*,*Weight* and *City* with -1, 0 and +1.
E.g., the first row would be multiplied 3*3*3 times:

```
John 1 63 144 OK M
John 1 63 145 OK M
John 1 63 146 OK M
John 1 64 144 OK M
John 1 64 145 OK M
John 1 64 146 OK M
     ... etc
```

I'm thinking something like a loop:

```
data test2;
set test;
do i = -1 to 1;
    do j = -1 to 1;

        do k = -1 to 1;


        end;

    end;

output;
end;
run;
```

, but I cannot see how to set this up properly.

Comment: Thanks for posting data as a data step!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to add the increments for the variables.

```
data test;
    input ID $ Week Age Weight City $ Sex $;
    datalines;
John 2  64 145 OK M
Gary 3  46 176 OM M

;
run;

data want;
    set test;

    do j=-1 to 1;
        weight = weight + j;

        do k=-1 to 1;
            age = age + k;

            do l = -1 to 1;
                week = week + l;
                output;
            end;


        end;
    end;

    drop j k l;
run;
```

Comment: Thank u for this! So SAS overwrites the existing week, age and weight variables - no questions asked?

Comment: Yes, I double checked this and realized I needed to move the OUTPUT statement to the inner most loop.